# private int value not changed by class function

Tags: c++

I have a private int index here.

```
class classname {

  private:
    int index;
  public:
    classname();
    void stuff();
}
```

and in my constructor I initialize the `index = 10;`

```
classname::classname {
    index = 10;
}
```

but I want to change it in my `stuff()` function, so I did this

```
classname::void stuff() {
  cout << "the current index is: " << index << endl;
  index = 15;
  cout << "ending index is: " << index << endl;
}
```

in my main file I have

```
int main() {
    classname name;
    name.stuff();
    name.stuff(); //do it again
}
```

the second time it returns to 10 again but it should return 15 instead.
here is the result:

```
 the current index is: 10
 ending index is: 15
 the current index is: 10
 ending index is: 15
```

please help

Comment: If you fix the syntax errors you have, it works on my machine. Please post the actual (runnable) code you wrote.

Comment: so I test it using cout  at the beginning of the function and at the end of the function, it does give me 10 at the beginning and 15 at the end, the second time I call the function it gives me 10 again at the beginning and 15 at the end. (i am sorry I can't really put the whole code up)

Comment: The issue is that if I fix your code to work and then call cout in the appropriate spots it gives 10, 15, 15 on my computer. If you can't give the full code, then I cannot help you as I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: When I fix `classname::void stuff() {` to being `void classname::stuff() {`, and put all the code into one file, I get the output you expect.   My guess, like others, is that the code you posted is not representative of your actual code.   If the ACTUAL code is too large, create the smallest possible sample of code (e.g. by eliminating unrelated parts) that actually exhibits the problem and post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this fix: call index using classname::index

because you access private member using scope resolution operator (::)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class classname {
private:
int index;
public:
classname();

void stuff();
};
classname::classname() {

classname::index = 10;

cout<<classname::index<<endl;
}
void classname::stuff() {

cout<<"Current: "<<index<<endl;

classname::index = 15;

cout<<"ending: "<<index<<endl;
}

int main() {
classname name;
name.stuff();
name.stuff(); //do it again
return 0;
}
```

Comment: nope adding class header did not work. good idea though, I thought that would work

Comment: it worked for me. can you show me your updated code.

Comment: did you tried running my code first? if still not working you can send me your private code

Comment: lol so apparently after I restart the project it started working. I don't know what happen there though, maybe a bug.

Comment: I am going to give you the right answer because i didn't even think of that, and if someone meet some similar problem, it will most likely solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is misleading. It completely ignores the fact that the OP has not posted real code and that when you fix the obvious syntax errors, everything works as expected. The supposed "fix" has nothing to do with the problem at all.